# confusion matrix for given code.Dataset contain 6 classes only no labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, confusion-matrix

the dataset split into validation and training set.i use a mobilenet model. i get an accuracy of 97%. but the confusion matrix is only showing 16. i dont know how to code for confusion matrix.help me code for confusion matrix and classification report.

```
 train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input,
                                                     validation_split=0.30)
    
    train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/gdrive/My Drive/combin',
                                                     target_size=(224,224),
                                                     batch_size=32,
                                                     class_mode='categorical',
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     subset='training')
    
    
    validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                                                  '/content/gdrive/My Drive/combin', # same directory as training data
                                                    target_size=(224,224),
                                                    batch_size=1,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    shuffle=True,
     

                                               subset='validation') # set as validation data
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense,GlobalAveragePooling2D

# parameters for architecture
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
num_classes = 6
conv_size = 32

# parameters for training
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 20

# load MobileNet from Keras
MobileNet_model = MobileNet(include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

# add custom Layers
x = MobileNet_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)

Custom_Output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
# define the input and output of the model
model = Model(inputs = MobileNet_model.input, outputs = Custom_Output)
        
# compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    optimizer='adam',
                    metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

model.summary()


#Confution Matrix and Classification Report
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['1', '2', '3','4','5','6']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are creating the classification report and the confusion matrix

Comment: Could you please add it to your post as a codelisting?

Comment: Try `y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=-1)` with axis=-1 instead of 1